# How do I get all the files with a particular extension inside a directory?

Tags: windows, cmd, terminal

I need to get all the files with a particular extension inside a folder without having to cd into that folder in cmd.

Some thing similar to a path in bash: /path/to/my/directory/*.txt

I have tried this path in cmd: D:\path\to\my\directory*.txt
But it gives me No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works much like in bash (with `dir` instead of `ls`, and with backslashs):

```
dir "D:\path\to\my\directory\*.txt"
```

Don't forget the backslash in front of "*".

Comment: actually, the mistake that I made was my path had space in between due to which it was giving me an error, and after seeing those " a realized i need to add them. :p Thanks